# provide password in command and execute

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Linux Shell Scripting.I need to execute a shell script that gets username, password, host-name, command-to-be-executed as 1,2,3,4 parameters respectively.
I used ssh but it prompts for password. The main theme of this script is to execute a command from a remote server. Password security issues is not a problem. 
The main issue is that I must not be prompted for password input. Please help me solving this.

```
echo username = $1
echo Password = $2
echo Host-Name = $3
echo Command to Be executed = $4
set -x
expect -c "spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $1@$3 $4; expect \"*assword:*\"; send "$2\r";expect eof;"

echo "==============="
```

My Output:

```
username = root
Password = root@123
Host-Name = host-name
Command to Be executed = ls
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no root@host-name ls
root@123r===============
```

My command i.e. ls output is not getting displayed.

After using set -x before expect command:

Output:

```
username = root
Password = root@123
Host-Name = host-name
Command to Be executed = ls
+ expect -c 'spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no root@host-name ls; expect "*assword:*"; send root@123r;expect eof;'
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no root@host-name ls
root@123r+ echo 
===============
===============
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' root RHEL5 '~'
```

Comment: You can use password less(key-based) auth. Or You can try `expect` to provide password.

Comment: how to do with expect command? I have updated my question, Please suggest

Comment: any suggestions please.

Comment: Add escape char before `"` in send. Example `send \"$2\r\"` Accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
expect -c "spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $1@$3 $4; expect \"*assword:*\"; send \"$2\r\";expect eof;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following shell command:

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh USERNAME@SERVER; expect password:; send "PASSWORD\n"; interact'
```

You might not have `expect` in your linux system, but I think you can have it installed easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo username = $1
echo Password = $2
echo IP-Address= $3
echo Command to be executed= $4
expect -c "spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $1@$3 $4; expect \"*assword:*\"; send $2\r; expect eof"
```

And for key-based login, Follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) link. For this you need to generate public and private keys with empty passphrase. And Add your public key to remote machines USER/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: I am not getting the desired output.It displays   
username = root
Password = root@123
Host-Name = host-name
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no root@host-name ls
root@123
===============

Comment: Same script is working for me. I am getting `ls` output. Could you please post full error log ?

Comment: No Error appears. It jus comes out of the script to command mode

Comment: No idea. Are you sure your ssh is working? Try manually first. Add `set -x` at the beginning and provide the output.

Comment: I can see that `\r` is missing in `send PASSOWRD\r`. Please update your script.

Comment: I have written, please find the updated code in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55965/discussion-between-sanket-parmar-and-user3318138).